# Display an image from a XML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a XML file with the some data. I am able to read and display the text. I am now trying to read and display the image from the XML file.

I think I am able to read the image file tag but it gives me an error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" when I try to display it. I want the image to be displayed inside a div.

I have tried `console.log(img);` and it displays `images/empire_burlesque` and `images/hide_your_hearts`.

I want to do this using Javascript.

**XML FILE**

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <IMAGE>images/empire_burlesque.jpg</IMAGE>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <IMAGE>images/hide_your_hearts.jpg</IMAGE>
    </CD>
<CATALOG>
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "text.xml", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

        for ( i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            //Here I want to image to be displayed inside a div.                
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = img;


}
</script>

<div id="contentimage1">
<img id="img1" height="100%" width="100%" >
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using innerHTML? what happened to src?

Comment: @hunzaboy I just tried .src and it's now showing a small defualt image icon but not the image itself

Comment: yes because you are not adding extension. add .jpg or .png depending upon your image type.

Comment: Sorry the xml meant to have the .jpg extension but still doesn't display the image

Comment: can you share the html it is generating?

Comment: GET file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Song%20Web/images/empire_burlesque.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ... this is shown in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136350/discussion-between-anotheruser-and-hunzaboy).

Comment: So your `images` folder is in the same folder as your HTML document, yes?

Comment: Why `file:///` URLs? Are you not properly testing this via HTTP(S)? (In that case making AJAX requests in the first place should be problematic, IIRC most browsers only allow that when specifically configured to do so.)